# How to get Apple App IDs from given bundle ID?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have a list of Apple app bundleIds (e.g. com.facebook.Facebook).  What I am ultimately trying to achieve is to enrich this data with iTunes metadata, which is available via the iTunes Search API: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

I can get the specific information for a specific app if I know the app id (technically, the "trackId"), like so:
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284882215 (284882215 being the trackId for the Facebook app)

However, I cannot use the bundleId in the same way.  How can I systematically retrieve the app id (aka trackId) given the bundleId?

Comment: answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11626157/41948

HTH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

`curl https://itunes.apple.com/lookup\?bundleId\=com.facebook.Facebook`

In the results you should see things like:

> ```
>   "trackViewUrl": "https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/app\/facebook\/id284882215?mt=8&uo=4",
> ```
>
> "bundleId": "com.facebook.Facebook",
>
> "trackId": **284882215**,

Comment: `curl -s "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=uk.co.guardian.iphone2"`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [David Richardson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801221/617864) answer, here's my slightly modified version that uses [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the JSON and extract just the App ID:

```sh
$ myApp=WireGuard
$ bID=$(mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -r "/Applications/${myApp}.app")
$ curl -s "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=${bID}" | jq -r '.results[0].trackId'
1451685025
```