# Get other application icon image in my Application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, imageicon

In my application, I am showing some applications list which are on app store.

I want to get those application's icon image in my application.

I just search but not getting any relevant post on this.

Is there any way to get it? Apple allows to get? Please suggest if there is any way.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the downvot, can you please write reason too?

Comment: I can't understand question. You need icon's of apps in AppStore or installed on device?

Comment: ok, I mean i want it for apps which are on app store, Doesn't matter either is on device or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

apple has an **JSON Service** for that, where you get a lot of meta data for every application

This is the URL for the Facebook App
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284882215

and this a the URL for the Facebook and Twitter App combined:
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284882215,333903271

in the JSON you will find **URLs of the app icons** in attributes artworkUrl60, artworkUrl512 and artworkUrl100

"artworkUrl100":"http://a1170.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/37/7e/9e/377e9e31-388e-8d10-e414-f478a2f18d29/mzl.pacepjmm.png"

**unfortunately those app icons are squared** and don't have the rounded corners, you will get app icon how the developer uploaded it.

**UPDATE: get data for other countries**

if you want to get the data for different countries you can just add the country code in between e.g.

- for Germany: http://itunes.apple.com/de/lookup?id=284882215
- for France: http://itunes.apple.com/fr/lookup?id=284882215

Comment: Yes, getting from above. Thanks.

Comment: Can you get the ID from the bundle identifier? Edit: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000667/how-to-get-apple-app-ids-from-given-bundle-id

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an tool to generate AppStore Custom RSS Feeds, it returns links and icons, bu i had never worked on it.

iTunes RSS, With the [iTunes Store RSS Feed Generator](http://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator/) you can create custom RSS feeds to fit your specific needs. Specify feed length, genres, types, and more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply let me check once with this way.