# Is there a known database or a way to retrieve icons of different apps

Tags: ios7, icons

I am building some software that requires me to display the icons of different apps, and possible save them on a database so I can look it up on demand?

I know you can get the url scheme but is that all you can do with it ? Or is there a way to get the app icons ?

For instance is there a way to get the icon of angry birds via an API call to the IOS system ?

Answer (score 0):

In a non-jailbroken iPhone, you cannot get it from the OS.

You need to query the iTunes service from Apple to get this info ex:
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284882215

See this SO post for more detail
[Get other application icon image in my Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657185/get-other-application-icon-image-in-my-application)