# Testing Facebook iOS requests before publishing in App Store?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm able to successfully send requests through the Facebook iOS SDK, however the notifications do not appear in the user's iOS app. Based on other answers on here, I've determined this is because I do not have a iPhone Store ID configured in my FB developer settings. However, my iPhone Store ID won't work because I haven't published the app yet...so how does one test Facebook iOS requests before publishing their app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only solution is to use the app ID of an already published app for testing, and then change to the actual app ID when you publish your app. If you don't have access to a published app ID, I found this solution for finding one: [Get iTunes App Store ID of an app itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717159/get-itunes-app-store-id-of-an-app-itself)